# React - How to view image from token url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

after submit image to firebase, url which I got from server with format following:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/endgame.appspot.com/o/photos%2F1590120086477.jpg?alt=media&token=09eee233-fa8a-473a-a981-19a59b60cb57
```

I tried copy above (format) url to browser & run it, it works, however it return nothing when I push url into Image

```
<Image source={{ uri: this.state.post.image }} />
```

If you met this problem, please help me way fix it, thanks your interest!

Comment: Do you have an Image componet?

Comment: If Yes can you post that component somehow so  I can have a look

Comment: @FridayAmeh I grab whole object from firebase, at other positions I set up corresponding elements success, this.state.post.title, this.state.post.content ...only left image, Image can't treat with token url as normal url ...

Comment: nevermind, my bad (I didn't set width & height for image) Good day, man!